# Как в NetBeans генерировать toString не в одну строку?

Tags: java, netbeans

Подскажите, есть ли возможность заставить NetBeans генерировать toString не в одну строку?
Сейчас так:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "DataContainer{" + "index=" + index + ", description=" + description + '}';
}
```

Надо так:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "DataContainer{" 
           + "index=" 
           + index 
           + ", description=" 
           + description 
           + '}';
}
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под словом "генерировать"?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно как в IntelliJ можно обойтись с простым заменой.

1. Включите Regular expression, иконка (.*)
2. Найти `\+ \",`
3. Заменить на `\+ \r \",`
4. Shift + Alt + F - форматировать

Вот и все :)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы когда-нибудь пользовались NetBeans, то должны знать, что метод toString, генерируемый с помощью IDE, выводит все поля в одной строке, что, мягко говоря, не удобно. Особенно если вы имеете дело с DTO, содержащим большое количество полей. Intellij Idea справляется с этим вопросом гораздо лучше и код выглядит намного эстетичнее. Так понятно?